# Running two gulp.watch tasks in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, typescript, gulp

I have been having trouble running two separate gulp watches as my default task. Here is my gulpfile.babel.js

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import git from "gulp-git";
import ts from "gulp-typescript";

const tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

export function watchTs() {
  gulp.watch(
    // details omitted...
  );
}

export function watchGit() {
  gulp.watch(
   // details omitted...
  );
}

export default function(cb) {
  gulp.parallel(watchTs, watchGit);
}
```

And this is what happens when I run gulp:

```
master* $ gulp                                                                [16:21:52]
[16:21:54] Requiring external module @babel/register
[16:21:55] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/github/screeps/gulpfile.babel.js
[16:21:55] Starting 'default'...
[16:21:55] The following tasks did not complete: default
[16:21:55] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

I can get the right result by running: `gulp watchTs & gulp watchGit`.
Why is this not working?

Comment: It might have worked if you called the `cb()` function after the `parallel` line.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I thought the default needed to be a function I defined, but this works.

```
export default gulp.parallel(watchTs, watchGit);
```

I'm still not 100% certain WHY the other method doesn't work though. Any feedback helping me understand would be welcome.